# OHTTPS + AFNetworking Mocking the Failure Response

Tags: ios, unit-testing, afnetworking, ohhttpstubs

I am currently using OHTTPStub to mock the responses of my AFNetworking calls. The AFNetworking calls return either a successful response or a failing response.

If I create a stub using "responseWithJSONObject" method, which is the only example provided or discussed concerning OHTTPStubs, then the success block of my AFNetworking calls is always executed.

So, what method do I need to call in order to execute the failure block of my AFNetworking methods.

I have already tried OHTTPStubs's "responseWithError" method, which does not call either the success or the failure block.

Answer (score 2):

Try adding this before your request is made.

```swift
NSError *error = [NSError errorWithDomain:@"YourDomainName" code:444 userInfo:infoDictionary];

[OHHTTPStubs stubRequestsPassingTest:^BOOL(NSURLRequest *request) {
    return YES;
} withStubResponse:^OHHTTPStubsResponse *(NSURLRequest *request) {
    return [OHHTTPStubsResponse responseWithError:error];
}];
```

This will stub all requests and return a response with status code 444. [The documentation for AFNetworking's acceptable status codes](http://cocoadocs.org/docsets/AFNetworking/2.5.4/Classes/AFHTTPResponseSerializer.html#//api/name/acceptableStatusCodes) shows that AFNetworking conforms to RFC 2616. [The RFC 2616 documentation](http://www.w3.org/Protocols/rfc2616/rfc2616-sec10.html#sec10.4) says that status codes 400-499 should be used for client errors and 500-599 for server errors. This means that any response AFNetworking receives with status code 400-599 will execute the failure block.